# mount synology NAS

Tags: mount, nas, synology, mount-point

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to mount a synology NAS.

I have followed all indications on https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

However I still get the error message when trying to mount the disk:

> sudo mount 192.168.0.3:/volume1/video /mnt mount: wrong fs type, bad
>   option, bad superblock on 192.168.0.3:/volume1/video,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
>          need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try

Answer (score 0):

You need to install nfs-common before you try to mount the remote share.